# Gear VR - You are not a developer

Tags: android, gear-vr, deviceid

I'm wanting to build an application for the Gear VR for my senior Project. I went to application manager, gear vr service, managed storaged, vr service, storage, manage storage, and then finally click on VR Service Version several times. It runs through my apps on my phone and then says that I am not a developer. When looking online, it said I needed an APK signed with my devices osig file. I think I found the page to get the osig file (https://dashboard.oculus.com/tools/osig-generator/) but I know know how to get my devices ID. I can find the sn and imei,  but they say it is not the correct id. I'm also not sure how to get the APK signed with this file. Any help would be great on this process.

Comment: Have you got any solution on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple questions

1) Enable developer support on your phone:

In your phone, in Settings->About Device->Build number
press the 'Build number' menu item about five times until the screen displays 'you are now a developer!'. Now a new menu item settings->'Developer Options' should appear on your phone. 
Be sure settings->'Developer Options'->USB debugging check box is checked, and accept any prompt that asks you to accept connection between your computer and phone.

2) Getting the Device ID:

You need to install the Android SDK, and on a command prompt, go to where adb.exe is located and type
adb devices
If your device is connected AND developer mode enabled, it should display something like
List of devices attached
13157df384099f3t        device

That long number/letters is your device ID

3) How to get your APK signed:
You would place the osig file in your Android project and depends on how the project is set up, let any build script know where the osig file is. Let me know how your project is like and I can help further

Thanks